# How to create a postgreql crosstab query where the categories and many and dynamic

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I am trying to write a script that outputs a sample-species matrix, where the row header is the species, the column header is the sample type, and the value is the species abundance. The problem i am having is that the column header is dynamic for every job, and can be very large, in the case below we get 93 column categories. I cant possibly manually define the column headers for 93 categories, only to have to edit the list for the next job when there are only 20 column categories for example.

So how do i get the distinct list of samples and then pass that list into the crosstab portion of the query (no i have not written the crosstab portion of the query here yet).

> SELECT
> sitename ||'-'||smpl_method||'-'||samplenumber as sample,
> name,
> commname,
> name ||' - '||commname as fullname,
> abundance,
> class_name`
> FROM(
> SELECT
> (dense_rank() OVER (order by public.data_sites_samples.id)) AS samplenumber,
> public.data_sites.id_job,
> public.data_sites.sitename,
> public.data_sites_samples.smpl_method,
> public.data_sites_samples.id AS id_sample,
> public.data_species.taxonid,
> SUM(public.data_species.num_individs)as abundance,
> public.tax_species.name,
> public.tax_species.verancular as commname,
> public.tax_families.class_name
> FROM
> public.data_sites
> INNER JOIN
> public.data_jobs
> ON (public.data_sites.id_job = public.data_jobs.id)
> INNER JOIN
> public.data_sites_samples
> ON(public.data_sites.id = public.data_sites_samples.id_site)
> INNER JOIN
> public.data_species
> ON(public.data_sites_samples.id = public.data_species.id_sample)
> INNER JOIN
> public.tax_species
> ON(public.data_species.taxonid = public.tax_species.taxonid)
> INNER JOIN
> public.tax_genera
> ON(public.tax_species.id_genera = public.tax_genera.id)
> INNER JOIN
> public.tax_families
> ON(public.tax_genera.id_family = public.tax_families.id)
> WHERE
> public.data_sites.id_job = 2077 AND
> public.data_sites_samples.smpl_method <> 'OPP'
> GROUP BY
> public.data_species.taxonid,
> public.data_sites.id_job,
> public.data_sites.sitename,
> public.data_sites_samples.smpl_method,
> public.data_sites_samples.id,
> public.data_species.taxonid,
> public.tax_species.name,
> public.tax_species.verancular,
> public.tax_families.class_name,
> public.data_species.date_collected
> ORDER BY
> public.data_sites.sitename,
> public.data_sites_samples.smpl_method,
> public.data_species.date_collected)
> AS TABL_A;

To be honest I dont really know where to start to even try to pass a list to the crosstab column definition component of the query

Comment: *Do not even try crosstab.* Pivoting in not something SQL is good at, it must know the exact columns to process. If those change columns change you must rewrite the query, which means you must know them in advance. The other alternative is to write procedure code that writes the query then executes it.  This is a poor design as the entire pivot operation is for display purposes. Use SQL to extract and sort the data. Use your apps presentation manager to perform the pivot.